Is there a linear correlation between polarizability and the concentration of sucrose in water? (At low concentrations)
I don't see why the relationship between concentration and polarizability would be non-linear; however, I can't find any literature on the topic.
I'd expect a different behaviour at concentrations near saturation, however, I'm only looking at relatively low concentrations (600 gr/L) take into account that the solution becomes saturated at 2000 gr/L.
